# Excel 2007 Refresh Imported CSV File From Web

Tags: excel, csv, import

Log data from a test is uploaded to a web service, and the processed CSV is downloaded back into Excel for viewing in charts. At the moment, this is done via copy and paste for short CSV files and the Data > From Text feature for larger CSV files. Unfortunately, this takes a bunch of time for every test, and I need to make the process very simple for someone else to update the Excel spreadsheet.

The Excel spreadsheet contains 5 raw-data pages which are used to store the CSV from the server. I have no issues selecting Data > From Text, entering the website URL, and completing the format to import. This process can be repeated (same as the Copy and Paste) for all 5 pages to import the data.

This process only allows me to put in one filename, so I am using the same URL for the data, and having PHP return the CSV of the latest (or a specifically configured) test whenever the website is accessed. I've verified that this process is working correctly.

Unfortunately, when I do 'Refresh All', it prompts for a filename unless I go to Data > Connections > Properties, and uncheck 'Prompt for file name on refresh'.

However, even when I do that, I'm getting mixed results. Sometimes only one of the pages will update. (Seems to be the last one I set up.) Sometimes none of them do. I need a solution which updates all 5 pages based on the current CSV from the server without having to set up the connections again every time. Ideally I'd like to just hide these raw data sheets so we can have an Excel file that's just the final charts.

Surely this is a common function and I am doing something wrong, yet all the guides I try on the Internet don't seem to work. For example, this one:
http://www.kimgentes.com/worshiptech-web-tools-page/2010/8/18/web-connecting-csv-files-as-external-data-to-excel-spreadshe.html [URL is corrected]
Seems like they only set up one connection. I can get one working to refresh, but not more than one.

Comment: I use that exact example in a spreadsheet that has dozens of sheets importing from 45 different web CSV files. It didn't cause a problem using multiple links, at least in my spreadsheet. One thing I did notice was that I had to put the spreadsheet into some sort of Windows security folder because it was concerned about downloading files. The other thing was the user/pwd had to initially be entered 3x for each sheet so it was properly stored in Windows password locker/cache. But after all that, it now works without doing anything more than "Refresh All" and all 45 CSVs get reloaded.

Comment: Perhaps if you can give a screen shot or something showing what you are doing or showing the errors, that might make it a bit easier to help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen and finally figured it out. There are actually 3 things that can happen to give this result, and a separate solution for each:

1. First, Excel software uses the IE 11 web object to when it does web
   retrieval of data. This means it will be "sticky" to sessions using
   IE11 to access the data. Most websites these days are run by cloud
   servers, which generate sessions on the server with the most load.
   This normally has no impact on users on web browsers since they
   login and can visually enter their credentials etc. But when a
   program accesses a website and must use a specific web browser, it
   must use the properties of that browser and how it works. I ran into
   this a lot when I would generate and be able to download my CSV
   files on the website in Chrome, then try to use Excel to import the
   same files wouldn't work (it would say they weren't there).  The
   solution to this, at least for now, is to use IE 11, login to the
   website, generate the CSV files and test that they can be
   downloaded. Then use Excel to run the web import and it should pick
   up the same sticky session to get the CSV files.
2. Second, password entry is a different thing, but also has to do with the stickiness
   of the data. For some reason Excel will not cache your credential
   responses for logging into a website without you entering them 3
   times. This experience may change for you, but I found that I must
   enter a new credential set (for a new web import of a CSV) 3 times
   before it becomes permanently cached by Excel. After this, I don't
   have the problem.
3. Third, most complex Excel programs that require
   web import may also require that you either import local data you
   downloaded from a website, import data from a website into a sheet
   or run more complex objects like Macros. All of these need proper
   permissions. You may need to set your Trust Center settings to allow
   you to use your Excel program on your computer in this way. That is
   part of MS office.  You can set add and update those as per MS info
   here:
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4